# Vue 3: What's the proper way of handling event listeners like "visibilitychange" and "offline"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-listener

**Note A:** I'm not talking about event listeners on elements, like @click

**Note B:** I've been looking "all over" for this but couldn't find it anywhere. Feel free to slap my face if the answer is out there.

**Note C:** I'm a beginner with Vue trying to learn stuff

I guess I could put those kind of event listeners within **main.js**, but that just seems a bit off? Also how would I **call functions** declared within App.vue from main.js?

I'm guessing there's a better and more proper way to handle this within App.vue and the life cycle?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here are two vanilla JS code examples, one with **window** and one with **document**:

```js
window.addEventListener('offline', function() {
  alert('You seem to be offline!');
});

document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
  if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
    alert('Hello again!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the event listener in the `created` or `mounted` hook in your SFC like this:

```
<script>
export default {
  created () {
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', this.handleVisibility, false)
  },
  methods: {
    handleVisibility (e) {
      if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
        // do what you like
      } else {
        // again do as you like
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Glad it worked! You can also remove the event listener in the `destroyed` hook (if necessary).